# What is the correct way to install homebrew on a MacBook Pro M1, 2020?

Tags: python, gcc, homebrew, cython, macos-mojave

Specifically I am trying to learn about cython and compiling. I was told to install **homebrew** (/opt/homebrew/), **gcc**, **python development version**, and lastly **cython**. Unfortunately I keep running into issues when attempting to compile from python to C/++, these issues seem to be with the way they are installed. I’ve tried so many things to attempt to fix the errors but nothing has worked, So my plane was to uninstall and reinstall the correct way, and I was hoping someone would be able to help me with this.

NOTE -> using rosetta2 terminal, visual studio code and also have anaconda installed.

**Questions:**

1. Should I be running on Rosetta2 or M1 native architecture?
2. Proper ways to install homebrew, cython, gcc, and python dev version.

Thank you!